# difference beetween print('a') and 'a'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very beginner at python. When using the Python console, I'm confuse about the difference beetween 'a' and print('a'), the output is 'a' and a, respectively. Could you explain to me in simple ways?

Comment: Can you provide a complete code? because your question is a bit strange, 'a' and print('a') don't do the same, but they might show up as a result of running PHP in the same or similar way. One is a value, another is the output of a function

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the console, the console will output the value of `repr`.

```
>>> print 'a'
a
>>> 'a'
'a'
>>> print repr('a')
'a'
```